# Tutorial, optimization part, 5_admm_optimizer has attribute error

Tags: programming, quantum-algorithms

In admm optimizer, when running the demo, it has attribute error, binary_vartype does not have attribute 'one_letter_symbol'. Does any one know how to solve it?
[image]

Here is the code:

```
import time
from typing import List, Optional, Any
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

from docplex.mp.model import Model

from qiskit import BasicAer
from qiskit.aqua.algorithms import QAOA, NumPyMinimumEigensolver
from qiskit.optimization.algorithms import CobylaOptimizer, MinimumEigenOptimizer
from qiskit.optimization.problems import QuadraticProgram
from qiskit.optimization.algorithms.admm_optimizer import ADMMParameters, ADMMOptimizer

# If CPLEX is installed, you can uncomment this line to import the CplexOptimizer.
# CPLEX can be used in this tutorial to solve the convex continuous problem, 
# but also as a reference to solve the QUBO, or even the full problem.
# 
# from qiskit.optimization.algorithms import CplexOptimizer

# define COBYLA optimizer to handle convex continuous problems.
cobyla = CobylaOptimizer()

# define QAOA via the minimum eigen optimizer
qaoa = MinimumEigenOptimizer(QAOA(quantum_instance=BasicAer.get_backend('statevector_simulator')))

# exact QUBO solver as classical benchmark
exact = MinimumEigenOptimizer(NumPyMinimumEigensolver()) # to solve QUBOs

# in case CPLEX is installed it can also be used for the convex problems, the QUBO, 
# or as a benchmark for the full problem.
#
# cplex = CplexOptimizer()

# construct model using docplex
mdl = Model('ex6')

v = mdl.binary_var(name='a')
w = mdl.binary_var(name='w')
t = mdl.binary_var(name='t')
u = mdl.continuous_var(name='u')

mdl.minimize(v + w + t + 5 * (u-2)**2)
mdl.add_constraint(v + 2 * w + t + u <= 3, "cons1")
mdl.add_constraint(v + w + t >= 1, "cons2")
mdl.add_constraint(v + w == 1, "cons3")

# load quadratic program from docplex model
qp = QuadraticProgram()
#qp.from_docplex(mdl)
print(qp.export_as_lp_string())
```

And here is the link to the tutorial: https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-tutorials/blob/master/tutorials/optimization/5_admm_optimizer.ipynb

Comment: Screenshots are bad, use copy-paste.

Comment: (Btw, while it is not the SO, the [same reason](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) passes also here.)